# BestWay to save small data incase of shutting down

Tags: c#

Every mintute I want to save some data incase of shutting down. the data is very small (words).

**Notes:**

1. **The file I save on, is writen concurrently, and Alot.
   Each thread will write something and then wont stop change it. Every new thread will add more text and change it's text too.**
2. most of what I write to it will be small words like addresses.
3. I need a good way of pulling out that information from the file in the best way. DB will be good but some programers say its for very big information only.
4. I dont care if the file's size.
5. I dont care about how much files I will have.

Thanks.

Comment: The important point here is number 1. Will the concurrent writes be effecting the same values?

Comment: Im sory but I couldnt understand you. Can you explain what do you mean?

Comment: Will the frequent writes be changing the same words or just appending to the text?

Comment: each thread will write something and then wont stop change it. Every new thread will add more text and change it's text too.

Comment: By "a lot" do you mean once a minute?

Comment: By "words" do you mean 10 `char`s, 100 `char`s, 1000000 `char`s?

Comment: What does "wont stop change it" mean?

Comment: By "adressess" do you mean postal addresses?

Comment: Basically, if you want to deal with Atomicity, Consistency, Isoloation or Durability of your changes use a database. If you want to change a postal address once a minute a text file will probably be fine and easier to set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a text file, you would have to make sure the file gets closed as the program shuts down.  If you intend to keep adding to the file then you would have to figure out a way to roll the file to another as it grows, this it not trivial.  Or you can just use something like SqLite which is a small footprint database and you won't have any trouble.

Comment: I will have too much context swiching on text file becouse of the concurrent writings. Meanwhile I will go read about SqlLite. Thanks

Comment: I think the correct way to say it is sqlite if we think about the same product : http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: Yes SqLite, thanks for catching the typo, I will update.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `DataTable()` and storing/Bind to that. Then every X amount of time you could do a:

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();
t.WriteXml(YourFileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

To recover use:

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();
t.ReadXml(YourFileName);
```